# ConnectionException: Modbus Error: [Connection] Failed to connect ModbusTcpClient

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pymodbus

I have been trying to read data from Modbus (Raspberry pi here) over Modbus TCP using pymodbus. I keep on getting the error unable to connect. Here is the code snippet producing this error.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

#modbus connection
client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.137.238')
connection = client.connect()

#read register
request = client.read_input_registers(1008,3)
result = request.registers
print(result)
```

I am running this locally on the pi. I get the following with ifconfig and have tried all the IP addresses with ModbusTcpClient. I'm not sure what am I missing here.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.137.238  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.137.255
        inet6 fe80::7ce5:23eb:968f:59de  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:46:d3:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 438  bytes 46776 (45.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 330  bytes 31566 (30.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1847  bytes 149291 (145.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1847  bytes 149291 (145.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.1.199  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.1.255
        inet6 fe80::7f47:6c9f:f1c:1274  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd9d:fbd1:372:0:7a9c:777b:a806:2350  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether dc:a6:32:46:d3:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 208  bytes 16783 (16.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 53  bytes 7372 (7.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have already seen this [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858823/modbus-error-failing-to-connect-to-modbustcpclient-when-reading-writing) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670419/modbus-tcp-ip-on-raspberrypi-wit-pymodbus). Also, pymodbus with pi works over RTU.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see - you want do get data from RPi? But seems to me your setup is for RPi to *get* data from a 'client' with it's own IP. I believe you need to set up a Modbus slave first to be able to present data with Modbus TCP.

Comment: Modbus slave is there, that's how I'm able to get data from RPi using Modbus RTU protocol. And yes, I'm trying to get data from the RPi

Comment: Then it would be interesting to see your slave setup. Also you may try to connect from PC first, with some simple sowtware like "Modus master tool".

Comment: Apparently, it was able to connect at port 22 and not at 502. But now it cannot recognise registers. And a different script running RTU recognise the registers with the same address.

Comment: I have posted the 2 scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68841668/modbus-rtu-works-but-modbus-tcp-doesnt-with-pymodbus?noredirect=1#comment121663499_68841668)

Comment: That's what I was talking about. Different port or slave number is often the reason master couldn't connect to slave over TCP.

Comment: Somehow "You need 50 reputation" to comment there. What I can say is
 1) that "waiting for 12000 bytes" is hardly what you meant, so maybe the settings for registers are interpreted like some huge number - you'd better check it with help/examples. RTU is much more tolerable on that matter an may forgive you "asking non-existent registers" from slave. 2) personally I had good experience with modbus_tk library.

Comment: I think you were also correct about the TCP slave server, I might have misunderstood you. Do you think it would be a good idea to use RTU as a master to read/write from registers and then use it t make a TCP slave server? The reason is because they are still communicating over RS485. Or can I still write a TCP salve that can read/ write values directly from registers?

Comment: Adding on to the previous comment, there are sensors connected directly to the ports.

Comment: AFAIK slave only presents data, master reads.

So if you have directly connected Modbus RTU sensors that you want to aggregate on RPI and translate further over Modbus TCP, then I think yes, you should go like that:

Sensors--->(Modbus RTU Master *RPI* Modbus TCP Slave)--->Server 
I.e. RPI should have both Master RTU and Slave TCP running and translate values between their registers programmicaly via variables (m.b. even dataframes).

Comment: Many thanks, this has been indeed helpful. Would you happen to know/ refer me to a minimal implementation for Modbus RTU Master RPi to Modbus TCP Slave for reading/ writing registers?

Comment: You're welcome.

Unfortunately, no. But I think it shouldn't be that hard. You might look at those two examples of mudbus_tk and see, if they appear easier for you than pymodbus:
https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/examples/rtumaster_example.py
https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/examples/tcpslave_example.py

Anyways, I'd suggest to start with just one value, and see how it goes. Since addressing tables in Modbus is always tricky.