# Modbus RTU works but Modbus TCP doesn't with pymodbus

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pymodbus

So I am trying to read registers from the RPi.

I can do it using the Modbus RTU using the following script

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB1', baudrate=38400, timeout=1)

client.connect()
print(client.connect)
read=client.read_input_registers (address = 1008 ,count =16, unit=55)

data=read.registers[int(0)] 
#print(data) #printing value read in above line
print(read.registers)
```

But when I try to over Modbus TCP, it fails. The connection can be established with the RPi and I'm trying to read the same registers as above. The script is:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#modbus connection
client = ModbusTcpClient('localhost',22)
connection = client.connect()
read=client.read_input_registers (address = 1008 ,count =16, unit=55)

print(read.isError)
if not read.isError():
    '''isError() method implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above'''
    print(read.registers)  # Note.
else:
    # Handle Error.
    print('Modbus Error:', read)
```

This is what I get:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:Connection to Modbus server established. Socket ('::1', 48225, 0, 0)
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x6 0x37 0x4 0x3 0xf0 0x0 0x10
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Incomplete message received, Expected 12852 bytes Recieved 48 bytes !!!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x53 0x53 0x48 0x2d 0x32 0x2e 0x30 0x2d 0x4f 0x70 0x65 0x6e 0x53 0x53 0x48 0x5f 0x37 0x2e 0x39 0x70 0x31 0x20 0x52 0x61 0x73 0x70 0x62 0x69 0x61 0x6e 0x2d 0x31 0x30 0x2b 0x64 0x65 0x62 0x31 0x30 0x75 0x32 0x2b 0x72 0x70 0x74 0x31 0xd 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.socket_framer:Processing: 0x53 0x53 0x48 0x2d 0x32 0x2e 0x30 0x2d 0x4f 0x70 0x65 0x6e 0x53 0x53 0x48 0x5f 0x37 0x2e 0x39 0x70 0x31 0x20 0x52 0x61 0x73 0x70 0x62 0x69 0x61 0x6e 0x2d 0x31 0x30 0x2b 0x64 0x65 0x62 0x31 0x30 0x75 0x32 0x2b 0x72 0x70 0x74 0x31 0xd 0xa
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.socket_framer:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
<bound method ModbusException.isError of ModbusIOException('No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response', 4)>
Modbus Error: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response
```

Can anyone please explain to me what am I missing here?

Using `pymodbus==2.5.2`.

**EDIT**

I'm not using both protocols at the same time. I want to start using the Modbus TCP. I can ping the RPi from my PC over the network.

Comment: ModbusRTU is over a serial port and Modbus TCP is over a network connection. Is the Modbus device actually connected both serial and TCP? Normally a device will be connected one way or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: That is right, it has both the options, Previously, I was doing it serially (which still works) but now I'm trying to do it over the network. It might be worth stating, I can ping the device from my PC over the network.